(HTTP code 500) server error - could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]
I've read numerous articles about this issue but haven't found a solution that works for me. I'm attempting to install a new system from scratch.
I have installed:

Ubuntu

ip@dev1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

ip@dev1:~$ uname -r
6.5.0-27-generic




basic dev libraries and tools



ip@dev1:~$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ip@dev1:~$ make --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.




CUDA Toolkit



Wed Apr 10 09:02:31 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.15              Driver Version: 550.54.15      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090        Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| 30%   24C    P8             13W /  450W |      14MiB /  24564MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2308      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                              4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+





docker



ip@dev1:~/Documents$ docker --version
Docker version 26.0.0, build 2ae903e




nvidia container toolkit



p@dev1:~/Documents$ apt show nvidia-container-toolkit
Package: nvidia-container-toolkit
Version: 1.14.6-1
Priority: optional
Section: utils
Maintainer: NVIDIA CORPORATION <cudatools@nvidia.com>
Installed-Size: 2,736 kB
Depends: nvidia-container-toolkit-base (= 1.14.6-1), libnvidia-container-tools (>= 1.14.6-1), libnvidia-container-tools (<< 2.0.0)
Breaks: nvidia-container-runtime (<= 3.5.0-1), nvidia-container-runtime-hook
Replaces: nvidia-container-runtime (<= 3.5.0-1), nvidia-container-runtime-hook
Homepage: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-container-toolkit
Download-Size: 923 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  Packages
Description: NVIDIA Container toolkit
 Provides tools and utilities to enable GPU support in containers.

N: There are 19 additional records. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.

However, despite completing all these installations, I got this error when I launch a container:
ip@dev1:~$ docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.4.3-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled 

I've tried all the solutions I've read about, but none seem to work for me. What can I try next?

Have you seen the notice on their main site: "The nvidia-docker wrapper is no longer supported..."

yes, sure, therefore i use this git hub and this link for installation

Try docker run with sudo.
